# Android replace with regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string in Android. I would like to wrap all the instances of 4 or more continuous digits with some html. I imagine this will be done with regex, but I have a hard time getting even the most basic regular expressions to work.

Can someone help me with this?

I would like to change:

```
var input = "My phone is 1234567890 and my office is 7894561230";
```

To

```
var output = "My phone is <u>1234567890</u> and my office is <u>7894561230</u>";
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This will do it:

```
String input = "My phone is 1234567890 and my office is 7894561230";
String regex = "\\d{4,}";
String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "<u>$0</u>");
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realize you can use $# with String.replaceAll. That makes life way easier. Thanks.

Comment: @Keppil,  whats is this "\\d{4,}" . i want replace an `<iframe src=` with `<a href=` tag keeping the url same. how to get this done?

Comment: @RahmathullahMPulikkal: `\\d{4,}` means 4 or more numbers. There are many posts on SO on how to search and replace strings, you should be able to find one to help you rather quickly.