# Remove comma in a string quote for a CSV line

Tags: java, android, regex

Currently, I tend to remove comma in a string for a CSV line.

Here are my expectation

```
    // (1) ",123,456,"     -> ",123456,"
    // (2) ","abc,def","   -> ","abcdef","
    // (3) ","123,456","   -> ","123456","
    // (4) ","abcdef,","   -> ","abcdef","
```

I wrote the following code

```
    String[] test = {
        "\",123,456,\"",
        "\",\"abc,def\",\"",
        "\",\"123,456\",\"",
        "\",\"abcdef,\",\""            
    };

    final Pattern commaNotBetweenQuotes = Pattern.compile("(?<!\"),(?!\")");

    for (String d : test) {
        System.out.println("O : " + d);
        String result = commaNotBetweenQuotes.matcher(d).replaceAll("");
        System.out.println("R : " + result);
    }
```

However, I fail in case (4)

Here is the output I get

```
O : ",123,456,"
R : ",123456,"

O : ","abc,def","
R : ","abcdef","

O : ","123,456","
R : ","123456","

O : ","abcdef,","
R : ","abcdef,","   <-- we expect the comma after "f" being remove, as 
                        it is inside string quote
```

May I know how I can further improve this regular expression pattern?

```
    final Pattern commaNotBetweenQuotes = Pattern.compile("(?<!\"),(?!\")");
```

I get the code from [Different regular expression result in Java SE and Android platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692458/different-regular-expression-result-in-java-se-and-android-platform)

What I understand on the pattern is that

> If a comma doesn't have double quote on its left AND on its right,
>   replace it with empty string.

I try to use

```
     final Pattern commaNotBetweenQuotes = Pattern.compile("(?<!\"),(?!\")|(?<![\"0-9]),(?=\")");
```

with idea

> If a comma doesn't have double quote on its left AND on its right,
>   replace it with empty string.
>
> OR
>
> If a comma has double quote on its right, and non-digit / non double
>   quote on its left, replace it with empty string.

However, the "solution" is not elegant. What I really want is, **remove the comma within string literal. remove comma within integer. retain comma used as CSV seperator.**

Try not to use `$1`, as Android will use "null" instead of "" for unmatched group.

Comment: what is wrong with your results

Comment: Honestly, using regex to parse CSV is a lot of trouble.  Try using opencsv. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Not. I'm actually currently using opencsv to perform parsing. The above step is to pre-filtering on some case which cannot handle by opencsv. for example : "this is string", 123, "this is another, string". There are in fact only 3 elements in the line, but opencsv treat them as 4.

Comment: I don't get your CSV pattern. Seems you arbitrarily know how to parse the string. The case (1) is `",123,456,"` is a quoted string with commas inside, but you let the result be: `",123456,"`. You removed the comma between the two outter commas. But in the case (4) you want to remove the comma in the string `"abcdef,"`.

Comment: is a bit confusing. in fact, our csv input has 2 type elements. 1 is literal string, another is integer. for, take an example "string", 123,456, "string". it should really be filtered to "string", 123456, "string"

Comment: for case 4, since it is "comma in a string literal", not "comma in integer", we want to remove it for easy processing

Comment: You case 3 is failing as well;

Comment: The pattern `If a comma doesn't have double quote on its left AND on its right, replace it with empty string.` is correct. The case 4 is not replaced because it does not have a double quote on the left side. And the pattern says **AND**, so you have to have both.

Comment: @acdcjunior is right, case (4) `","abcdef,","` is wrong. First, it starts with one quote. That's not an empty string nor a literal. If you are passing a partial part of a CSV, make sure that you have complete fields. If that a partial CSV string, then all your tests will lead you to undefined behaviours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

To replace all the commas stuck in the middle of the strings use following, the empty capture group `(\b)` should avoid problem with android where if the back reference `$#` is not matched then language inserts a null character instead of nothing:

Regex: `((?:",\d|\d,")|",")|(\b),`

Replace with: `$1`

[image]

Input

```
",123,456," 
","abc,def","
","123,456"," 
","abcdef,","
```

Output

```
",123456," 
","abcdef","
","123456"," 
","abcdef","
```

## Disclaimer

This assumes the commas you want to keep are all surrounded by quotes like `"alpha","beta","1234"`

Comment: Thanks. However, using $1 will yield problem in Android platform as you can see in my link. That's why I avoid them :)

Comment: See article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377838/android-replace-with-regex for how to use replace with $# format on the android platform

Comment: The link is not relevant, as the "problem" in Android is that, for unmatched group, they are replacing it with "null" instead of ""

Comment: @Denomales The first result does not yield what the OP wants. For input `",123,456,"` the OP wants the output: `",123456,"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find second occurence of , in your String and then replace it with "". Here you have some examples:

- [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976616/how-to-find-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string)